Vault does not return token renewed by script
I write a script for renewing Hashicorp Vault tokens. But I faced an issue. When the token renewed automatically by the script Vault retuns n/a instead of token value so I cannot save it anywhere, to kubernetes secret, for example.
Output looks like this:
---                  -----
token                n/a
token_accessor       -------------
token_duration       10h
token_renewable      true
token_policies       ["default"]
identity_policies    []
policies             ["default"]

My script:
import subprocess
import json
from kubernetes import client, config

def renew_vault_token(vault_pod, token_id):
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(
            ['kubectl', 'exec', '-ti', vault_pod, '-n', 'vault', '--', 'vault', 'token', 'renew', '-accessor', token_id],
            capture_output=True, text=True, check=True
        )

        output = result.stdout
        print("Vault renew output:", output)  # Debugging output

        token_line = next(line for line in output.splitlines() if line.startswith('token'))
        new_token = token_line.split(None, 1)[1]
        
        print(new_token)
        return new_token

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error renewing token: {e}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    VAULT_POD = 'vault-0'
    TOKEN_ID = '----------------'

    new_token = renew_vault_token(VAULT_POD, TOKEN_ID)


The Vault token value is not modified during renewal.

Thank you, Matthew! I spent a couple of hours trying to fix the bug which does not exist... I will add an answer now in case somebody follow my way

Thanks for the comment above. I turned out that while vault token renew command the token value does not change. So the script for the token renew process looks like:
import subprocess
import json
from kubernetes import client, config

def renew_vault_token(vault_pod, token_id):
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(
            ['kubectl', 'exec', '-ti', vault_pod, '-n', 'vault', '--', 'vault', 'token', 'renew', '-accessor', token_id],
            capture_output=True, text=True, check=True
        )

        output = result.stdout
        print("Vault renew output:", output)

        return output

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error renewing token: {e}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    VAULT_POD = 'vault-0'
    token_ids = [
        '1ndTokenID',
        '2ndTokenID',
        '3rdTokenID'
    ]

    for token_id in token_ids:
        new_token = renew_vault_token(VAULT_POD, TOKEN_ID) 

